# How to check that certain date in between of date?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database in that there are two column start and end. start and end are in DD.MM.YYYY format.

I have a date which is also in DD.MM.YYYY format. **How can I check that my date is between start and end.**

Please suggest some query for checking these condition and fetching data from other column.

Comment: Save date in long formate and then compare

Comment: Have you tried sql `between` operator ? `SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN datevalue1 AND datevalue2`

Comment: *Why* are you storing dates in that format? If you stored them either as any of the natively-supported date-like types, you'd be fine... but DD.MM.YYYY isn't naturally sortable in a sensible way. I strongly recommend that you change how you store your dates - either to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` or to an integer number of seconds since the unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet wrote, you should have stored the dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

However, it might be possible to convert your date values into proper date values on the fly by reordering the fields (**if** the fields in the string have a fixed length):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE '2013-03-11' BETWEEN substr(StartDate, 7, 4) || '-' ||
                           substr(StartDate, 4, 2) || '-' ||
                           substr(StartDate, 1, 2)
                       AND substr(EndDate, 7, 4) || '-' ||
                           substr(EndDate, 4, 2) || '-' ||
                           substr(EndDate, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this below code. It will return number of days between two dates.
Date are in format YYYY-MM-DD

```
YourDatabse database=new YourDatabse (getApplicationContext(), 1);
 SQLiteDatabase sqlite=database.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor fetch=sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT julianday('"+date2+"') - julianday('"+date1+"')", null);
            fetch.moveToFirst();
            sqlite.close();
            int noOfDays=fetch.getInt(0);
```

Comment: But the dates *aren't* in that format in the database, so this will fail. Also, I'd very strongly recommend against building SQL queries like that. Use parameterized SQL instead.