# How to comare value from database fields

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a string date value in dd.mm.yyyy format. i have two column in database . both contains text values . This values are date in dd.mm.yyyy format. i want to compare my string date value with these .and want to check is it lies between these. i want to fetch data if my value is greater than first field and less than second then fetch some data. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your values are meant to be dates, why are you storing them as text?

Comment: (I see I asked you the same question before, and you ignored it then too...)

Comment: You asked a similar question today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332680/how-to-check-that-certain-date-in-between-of-date). Please add details to the original question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Convert you date value to Time In Milli second then compare this two value.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the sample codes which you can figure out the solution (Sqlite-PhoneGAp)

dont confuse with tx.ExecuteSQL() its for PhoneGAp

```
 if(sType=='select' && sMode=='select'){

                     //SELECT * from Em_Expense where strftime('%m', expdate)='06' and strftime('%Y', expdate)='2011'

                     tx.executeSql('SELECT expenseType,expdate,description,price,mode from Em_Expense where strftime(\'%m\', expdate)="'+sMonth+'" and strftime(\'%Y\', expdate)="'+sYear+'"', [],queryCustomSearchSuccess, errorCB);
                 }
                 else if(sMode=='select' && sType!='select')
                     {

                     tx.executeSql('SELECT expenseType,expdate,description,price,mode from Em_Expense where strftime(\'%m\', expdate)="'+sMonth+'" and strftime(\'%Y\', expdate)="'+sYear+'" and expenseType="'+ sType +'"', [],queryCustomSearchSuccess, errorCB);
                     }
                 else if(sType=='select' && sMode !='select')
                     {

                     tx.executeSql('SELECT expenseType,expdate,description,price,mode from Em_Expense where strftime(\'%m\', expdate)="'+sMonth+'" and strftime(\'%Y\', expdate)="'+sYear+'" and mode="'+ sMode +'"', [],queryCustomSearchSuccess, errorCB);
                     }
                 else
                     {
                     tx.executeSql('SELECT expenseType,expdate,description,price,mode from Em_Expense where strftime(\'%m\', expdate)="'+sMonth+'" and strftime(\'%Y\', expdate)="'+sYear+'" and mode="'+ sMode +'" and expenseType="'+sType+'"', [],queryCustomSearchSuccess, errorCB);
                     }
```