# How to perform arithmatic operation on Text data in android SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-widget

I am developing an android app where the database is already provided for sqlite.

In this database there is a table which has 'startDate' and 'endDate' fields in format "DD.MM.YYYY" which have the 'TEXT' datatype.

I get the DOB of the user using datapicker and convert it into the 'DD.MM.YYYY' format.

Now I want to fire select query on the above table to fetch all rows which dob lies between 'startDate' and 'endDate'

My problem is that how to perform arithmetic operations on text data types and I cannot modify my database.

I tried following query but did not get success:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE startData >= dob AND endDate <= dob;
```

Please guide me. I have searched a lot but could not get success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332680/how-to-check-that-certain-date-in-between-of-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BETWEEN for date range checks.

```
//Note that the date format is "YYYY-MM-DD"
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;
```

Comment: In android sqlite the default format is "YYYY-MM-DD" but in providing database my format is "DD.MM.YYYY". How could I perform between query on this date format?

Comment: check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) out and try to transform the date accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in your sqlite query write following function...

```
String[] getWeekCount(String start, String end)
{

    int i=0;
    String[] text=null;
    String selectQuery ="select * from tablename where date_col BETWEEN date ('" + start + "') and date('" + end + "')";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    try
    {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {  
            do 
            {
                 text[i]=cursor.getString(0).toString();
                             i++;
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else
            return 0;
        db.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception throw in SQLiteDBHandler"+e);
    }
    return text;
}
```