# Select data with current year

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to get all data from my table with only current year.
So, my table: DataApp. Column: id (integer), name(text), mydate(date)

```
----------------------------------
|  id  |    name   |    mydate   |
----------------------------------
|  1   |   first   |  01.01.2011 |
----------------------------------
|  2   |  second   |  09.03.2015 |
----------------------------------
```

I want to get only row with date 09.03.2015. I try to work with function strftime, because I develop for Android and function YEAR doesn't work.

I try it:

```
SELECT mydate FROM DataApp WHERE strftime('%Y', mydate) = '2015';
```

Column mydate is not involved in the comparison. How can I get year from mydate for comparison with '2015' in WHERE?

Comment: Does your query not work?  It looks correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Doesn't work :( There are no data in result of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) tells you which date formats are supported by `strftime()`.
`dd.mm.yyyy` is not among them.
You have to change the format of the date values in the database.

Comment: There are no other ways? Because this database already has many users.

Comment: You could [convert the data on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15333894/11654), with lots of `substr()` calls.